# WooCommerce - add new subtotal and re-order fields in order emails

Tags: woocommerce

I have a client which requires the order confirmation/completion emails to include the 'PO subtotal' which is the amount they will actually pay (product subtotal + shipping cost). We would also like to move the 'payment method' to the bottom of the list, and rename some others.

For example, the section of the email currently looks like this:

[image]

But the client needs it to look like this:

[image]

I don't need to update the website front or back ends, only the emails, although it doesn't matter if it also updates the front end. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be ok if it *did* update the display on the site as well? If so, the `woocommerce_get_order_item_totals` filter lets you re-arrange and add new rows there.

If not, you could:

- Find a way of identifying whether that filter's being called in the context of the email(s) you're targeting. I think you can check each `WC_Email`'s `$sending` for that.
- Customize `email-order-details.php` to do what you want (copied into your theme, not editing the original).